# how to mix the data in a sql script with the data of a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I recently had to add insert queries to a sql script that was provided to me

For example, I received this

```
/*
-- Query: select * from sometable where field1 = 1 order by 1 LIMIT 0, 300
*/

INSERT INTO `sometable` (`id`,`field1`,`field2`) VALUES (1000, 'data1', 'data2');
INSERT INTO `sometable` (`id`,`field1`,`field2`) VALUES (1001, 'data1', 'data2');
```

After adding some insert queries I conclude with a script that looks similar to this

```
/*
-- Query: select * from sometable where field1 = 1 order by 1 LIMIT 0, 300
*/

INSERT INTO `sometable` (`id`,`field1`,`field2`) VALUES (1000, 'data1', 'data2');
INSERT INTO `sometable` (`id`,`field1`,`field2`) VALUES (1001, 'data1', 'data2');
INSERT INTO `sometable` (`id`,`field1`,`field2`) VALUES (1002, 'data1', 'data2');
INSERT INTO `sometable` (`id`,`field1`,`field2`) VALUES (1003, 'data1', 'data2');
INSERT INTO `sometable` (`id`,`field1`,`field2`) VALUES (1004, 'data1', 'data2');
```

Now I need to mix this data with the data in the table. What is the correct way to do this?, because in the table there is still the subset of data from the original script. I hope I have explained myself well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use UNION and SELECT to get the data in a table form and then use WHERE clause to get the data you need. That would work if I have understood your question which I am not sure I have.

Comment: A table has _columns_, not _fields_...

Comment: you can use if not exists before your insert or just simply insert everything from your current table and your insert statement into a temp table and then take the union of those and write to your current table